# Web API Conversion

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I try to use web API using c#, entity, and MVC

```
private DBModel db = new DBModel();

    // GET: api/Employee
    public IQueryable<Employee> GetEmployees()
    {
        return db.Employees; 
    }
```

but it returns an error
'Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'.

[image]

DBContext

[image]

Model Class

[image]

Comment: I generated this code from 'WebAPI 2 Controller with actions, using Entity Framework'

Comment: Can you try `db.Employees.AsQuerable()`?

Comment: Yes, 'Just code' I tried that but the error is still there

Comment: The same error? Or a new error?

Comment: Maybe a type cast like this should work: `return (IQueryable<Employee>)db.Employees`?

Comment: Show us `DBModel`.  I suspect you are using the wrong class, and should be using one that implements `IQueryable<T>`  It looks like you're using a model where you should be using a context.

Comment: 'Just Code' Now it says 'Connot convert WebAPI.Models.Employee to WebAPI.Controller.Employee

Comment: As the exception said, you're using same `Employee` class name in different namespaces, try using fully-qualified name or alias instead.

Comment: Rename you controller to EmployeeController. Calling controller Employee is bad practice

Comment: Yes I changed the Class name from 'Employee' to 'EmployeesController' in Controller, Now it is working fine

Comment: Thanks, Bola, Tetsuya Yamamoto and all others who help me

Comment: Use the `.AsQueryable()` method

Comment: @Malshan I can not see you tried that.

Comment: In the future, don't paste *pictures* of code.  Paste it as *text*.

Comment: Ok I will do amy

Comment: Thank you 'Just Code' for your response but i tried that method

Answer (score 0):

Yes I changed the Class name from 'Employee' to 'EmployeesController' in Controller, Now it is working

```
public class EmployeesController : ApiController
{
    private DBModel db = new DBModel();

    // GET: api/Employees
    public IQueryable<Employee> GetEmployees()
    {
        return db.Employees;
    }
```